# Property of window is undefined in cypress

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress

I am using Cypress with Meteor.

I need the `Meteor` object on the window to call `Meteor.loginWithPassword`.

I want to use this to skip using the UI for login each time.
I have tried the following but Meteor is not on the window when it runs.

```
cy.window()
  .then((window) => {
      console.log(window.Meteor);
   });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
cy.window().its('Meteor');
```

This will wait until the `Meteor` property exists on the `window` object.

---

Or, if you want to do something with the `Meteor` property once it exists, use `.then()`:

```
cy.window().its('Meteor').then(meteor => {
    console.log(meteor);
    // do things
});
```

---

`.its()` will attempt to get a property from the object wrapped by Cypress, in this case the `window` object, and will retry until the property exists or the command times out.