# Get value of JS variable with Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

Is it possible to access a javascript variable with Cypress?
I want to geht the value of foo with Cypress.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    ...
    var foo='xyz';
    ...
}
```

```
cy.visit('abc.example.com')
cy.window().then((win) => {
            let foo=win.foo;
            cy.log(foo);
            
        });
```

Comment: What you want to do is impossible. `foo` is not in a global scope.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the same window object, for example:

**In the app**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    ...
    window.myVariable = "hello"
    ...
}
```

**In cypress**

```
cy.window().then(window => {
  //prints "hello"
  cy.log(window.myVariable) 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. This is the solution:

```
cy.window().its('myVariable').then(w => {
            cy.log(w);
        });
```

[Property of window is undefined in cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51496372/property-of-window-is-undefined-in-cypress)